# create array of all .elems found text content using .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
$( "ul.foundData li.id" ).each(function(index) {
    var allRelevantData = (index + ": " + $(this).text());
});
```

I am outputting it all to the console now, but I'd like to create a usable array out of the iteration output instead.

Comment: Variables? Why not just use an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to create an array based on iterating elements

```js
var data = $( "ul.foundData li.id" ).map(function(index) {
     return index + ": " + $(this).text();
}).get(); 

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="foundData">
<li class="id">Item 1</li>
<li class="id">Item 2</li>
<li class="id">Item 3</li>
<li class="id">Item 4</li>
<li class="id">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's like:

```
var allRelevantData = [];
$('ul.foundData li.id').each(function(i, e){
  allRelevantData.push($(e).text());
});
console.log(allRelevantData[0]); // first index
console.log(allRelevantData); // entire Array
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you mean with `usable array outside iteration output`.

but if you want to get the text content and "save" it in an array, then try this:

```
var data = [];
$( "ul.foundData li.id" ).each(function(idx, itm) {
    data.push(index + ": " + $(itm).text());
}); 

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourvariablearray = [];
$( "ul.foundData li.id" ).each(function(index) {
     yourvariablearray.push((index + ": " + $(this).text()));
});
console.log(yourvariablearray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JavaScript solution

```
var allRelevantData = Array.slice.call(null,document.querySelectorAll("ul.foundData li.id")).map(function(ele,index){
return index +" : " + ele.innerText;
});

console.log(allRelevantData[0])// 0 : Product 0
console.log(allRelevantData[1])// 1 : Product 1
console.log(allRelevantData[2])// 2 : Product 2
console.log(allRelevantData[3])// 3 : Product 3
```

Or if you want usable objects then yo can do like this:

```
var allRelevantData = Array.slice.call(null,document.querySelectorAll("ul.foundData li.id")).map(function(ele,index){
    return {index : ele.innerText};
    });

    console.log(allRelevantData[0])// {0 : "Product 0"}
    console.log(allRelevantData[1])// {1 : "Product 1"}
    console.log(allRelevantData[2])// {2 : "Product 2"}
    console.log(allRelevantData[3])// {3 : "Product 3"}
```